# ngb-pagination: bootstrap css is not working

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm working on an angular project with the latest version. I have a page where to display data from a database to a table. I've used the ng-bootstrap table along with its pagination. Everything is working, the data generation, the pagination as well as the item display per page except the styling of ng-pagination is not working. The following classes are `.pagination` `.page-item` and `.page-link`. Those classes can be found in `bootstrap.css`. I've included the latest bootstrap too. I know the `bootstrap.css` is working because the styling for table is working as well as the item per page selection.

I only included the `bootstrap.css` in one component.

I tried overriding it and no avail. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .css should be added to main.css